# Tensorflow 2 timeseries_dataset_from_array input vs target batch shapes difference

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

The new `tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array` function is used to create sliding minibatch windows over the sequential data, for example for tasks involving rnn networks.

According to the docs it returns a minibatch of inputs and targets. However, the target minibatch this function returns does not have a `sequence_length` (timesteps) dimension. For example.

```py
data = timeseries_dataset_from_array(
            data=tokens,
            targets=targets,
            sequence_length=25,
            batch_size=32,
        )

for minbatch in data:
    inputs, targets = minbatch
    assert(inputs.shape[1] == targets.shape[1]) # error
```

The `inputs` have `[32, 25, 1]` shape in case you already just have word indices there and `targets` confusingly have `[32, 1]` shape.

So, my question is how am I supposed to map a tensor of inputs with a window of 25 units to a target tensor with a window of 0 units?

How I always train sequence models is by feeding the input tensor of `[32, 25, 1]` which is then projected into `[32, 25, 100]` and then you feed the target tensor to the network of size `[32, 25, 1]` to your loss function or if you have multi-class problem a target vector of `[32, 25, num_of_classes]`.

That is why I am confused by the shape of the target tensor from `timeseries_dataset_from_array` and the intuition behind it.

Comment: It looks like this feature allows sequence to point learning only and not sequence to sequence. That's a common approach in NILM where you give a sequence to the model and only predict the target for the point in the middle (for example) of the sequence. That's the kind of shape you would expect for this approach.

Maybe you can try to generate both sequences in two different datasets first and then add the data of one as the target of the other.